# If condition Visualforce template for numeric field and multipicklist field

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have this 2 fields: Plot size (numeric field) and Parking type (multipicklist field).

I want the 2 fields to be displayed on my template only if there is a value otherwise they should not appear in the template.

Can you please help me with this

```
<tr style="font: bold 10px Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #201D21;background-color: #EBEBEC;">
                <td><apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.pba__Listing__c.fields.fm_Plot_size__c.Label}" />:</td>
                <td align="right"><apex:outputField value="{!listingData.listing.fm_Plot_size__c}"/> m<sup>2</sup> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="font: bold 10px Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #201D21;">
                <td><apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.pba__Listing__c.fields.fm_Parking_type__c.Label}" />:</td>
                <td align="right"><apex:outputField value="{!listingData.listing.fm_Parking_type__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a no layout output panel with an appropriate rendered attributerendered:

```
<apex:outPutPanel layout="none" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(listingData.listing.fm_Plot_size__c)),NOT(ISBLANK(listingData.listing.fm_Parking_type__c)))}">
            <tr style="font: bold 10px Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #201D21;background-color: #EBEBEC;">
                <td><apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.pba__Listing__c.fields.fm_Plot_size__c.Label}" />:</td>
                <td align="right"><apex:outputField value="{!listingData.listing.fm_Plot_size__c}"/> m<sup>2</sup> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="font: bold 10px Verdana, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #201D21;">
                <td><apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.pba__Listing__c.fields.fm_Parking_type__c.Label}" />:</td>
                <td align="right"><apex:outputField value="{!listingData.listing.fm_Parking_type__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
</apex:outPutPanel>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help it is working fine but because of the layout that I am using I would like to display just this sign - in case of no values. So instead of hiding the field I just want to display a symbol - Any idea on how to change the code to achieve that?

Comment: Think that should have been part of your question? And no idea. Maybe post up a new question and someone will figure it out for you.